# 'ReferenceError: driver is not defined' when I try to call a function from a loadable file

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

Good day. 
In JS/node I'm new.
I'm does made two functions from main code into a separate file and now I can not connect it to the main.
If I fighting over this issue. Help me plz. Something I'm doing wrong.

Here are the features that made:

```
exports.loadRegistrationForm = function() {
    driver.get('http://somesite');
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title){
        if("sometitle"===title){
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('html/body/div/header/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]'))
                  .click();
        };
    });
    driver.wait(function(){
        return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.name('fos_user_registration_form[email]'));
    }, 3000, 'Failed to load Registration form');       
}

exports.fillingRegistrationForm = function(inputEmail, inputPassword, errElement, errMessage){ 
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('fos_user_registration_form[email]'))
          .sendKeys(inputEmail); 
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword]'))
          .sendKeys(inputPassword); 
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('btn-submit')).click();//сабмит

    driver.wait(function(){
        return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.xpath(errElement));
    }, 3000, 'Элемент не найден'); 

    var flow = webdriver.promise.controlFlow();
    function getErrObject(){
        errObject = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(errElement))
                        .getText()
    } 
    flow.execute(getErrObject).then(function(){
        if(errObject.value_ === errMessage){
            assert.equal(errObject.value_, errMessage);
            console.log('OK')
        };
    });
}
```

Here are trying to rewrite part of the core functions:

```
var assert = require("assert")
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
            withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
            build();
var loadRegistrationForm = require('reusable_function').loadRegistrationForm;
var fillingRegistrationForm = require('./reusable_function').fillingRegistrationForm

describe('Check the Email field of the registration form.', function(){
    it('Enter an already registered Email', function(done){
        var inputEmail = '123@ya.ru';
        var inputPassword = '12345678Aa';
        var errElement = "//*[@class='form-errors server-error']";
        var errMessage = 'Email already in use';
        loadRegistrationForm();
        fillingRegistrationForm(inputEmail, inputPassword, errElement, errMessage);
        return done();
    });
});
```

In the console error:

```
     ReferenceError: driver is not defined
      at exports.loadRegistrationForm (C:\Program Files\nodejs\test\reusable_fun
ction.js:9:5)
      at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\test\test2_mocha.js:15:9)
      at callFnAsync (C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\moch
a\lib\runnable.js:306:8)
      at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\mocha\lib\runnable.js:261:7)
      at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\m
ocha\lib\runner.js:421:10)
      at C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.
js:528:12
      at next (C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\r
unner.js:341:14)
      at C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.
js:351:7
      at next (C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\r
unner.js:283:14)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\mocha\lib\runner.js:319:5)
```

What am I doing wrong? Incorrectly write access functions from loadable module? How does it right?

### Great thanks.

Upd. Okay I find answer.
Every module in JS have own scope. In module `reusable_function` no `driver` variable, hence the error `not defined`. `Driver` is a variable in the main module, but it is invisible to the module `reusable_function`, because it is not included in the scope. So I have defined a variable `driver` in the module `reusable_function` and removed this variable from the main module. To delete a variable from the main driver module does not disturb his work, because the variable `driver` cache and made available during the import module `reusable_function`.
Reusable_function:

```
var assert = require("assert")
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
            withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
            build()


exports.loadRegistrationForm = function(){
    driver.get('http:...');
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title){
        if("..."===title){
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('html/body/div/header/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]'))
                  .click();
        };
    });
    driver.wait(function(){
        return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.name('fos_user_registration_form[email]'));
    }, 3000, 'Failed to load Registration form');       
};


exports.fillingRegistrationForm = function(inputEmail, inputPassword, errElement, errMessage){ 
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('fos_user_registration_form[email]'))
          .sendKeys(inputEmail); 
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword]'))
          .sendKeys(inputPassword); 
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('btn-submit')).click();//сабмит

    driver.wait(function(){
        return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.xpath(errElement));
    }, 3000, 'Element not found'); 

    var flow = webdriver.promise.controlFlow();
    function getErrObject(){
        errObject = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(errElement))
                        .getText()
    } 
    flow.execute(getErrObject).then(function(){
        if(errObject.value_ === errMessage){
            assert.equal(errObject.value_, errMessage);
            console.log('OK')
        };
    });
};
```

Main module (part of):

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var flow = webdriver.promise.controlFlow();


var loadRegistrationForm = require('./reusable_function').loadRegistrationForm
var fillingRegistrationForm = require('./reusable_function').fillingRegistrationForm


describe('Check out Email form field.', function(){
    it('Enter already register Email', function(done){
        var inputEmail = '123@ya.ru'; 
        var inputPassword   = '12345678Aa';
        var errElement = "//*[@class='form-errors server-error']";
        var errMessage = 'Email already in use';
        loadRegistrationForm();
        fillingRegistrationForm(inputEmail, inputPassword, errElement, errMessage);
        flow.execute(function(){
            return done();  
        });
    });
});
```

Its work.

Comment: Where does `regForm` come from? What does the code around that line look like? The only mention of it in your question is in the error message.

Comment: the line (line 15 in the second snippet) that is just `function execute` - wrong - incorrect javascript syntax

Comment: I am sorry. There are no regForm. I will edited startpost.

Comment: Hi, all these functions are in one class or calling few functions from another class? As per Java, it looks like driver instance is not passed/utilized by those functions

Answer (score 0):

You have a random `funtion execute` right above the error line which ends without any code. Remove this and it will work.

Comment: I'm SO sorry. I tried to edit the code and forgot to undo the changes. Actually there is no function execute. But It really work, but there ane new trouble. Mocha give an error:      ReferenceError: driver is not defined. Why? It seems like function loadRegistrationForm() do no see various driver in main code.
I need open new topic or I can write about new trouble here?